# Fetch n latest records from Dynamo DB

Tags: java, amazon-dynamodb

I am having a dynamo db with a GSI on GSI_ID and range key on lastUpdatedId attribute. I want only 1 task to be rendered which is the latest on the basis of match. This is the expression I am using

```
DynamoDBQueryExpression<Record> exp =
                new DynamoDBQueryExpression<GoldDataRecord>()
                        .withIndexName(GSI_ID)
                        .withKeyConditionExpression(KEY_EXP)
                        .withExpressionAttributeValues(attrValues)
                        .withLimit(1)
                        // to get the results in descending order of last updated date giving the latest data first
                        .withScanIndexForward(false)
                        .withSelect(Select.ALL_ATTRIBUTES)
                        .withConsistentRead(false);

private DynamoDBMapper dynamoDBMapper;
PaginatedQueryList<Record> res = dynamoDBMapper.query(Record.class, exp);
```

But it is fetching all the records that are matching the GSI. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Please share code snippet after applying `exp` to line which says, more than 1 record is fetched

Comment: dynamoDBMapper.query(Record.class, expression);

Comment: As requested in above comment, will need to know how are you are working on `res` object. - "line which says, more than 1 record is fetched". Only then we will be able to guide.